# Winston verbose logger is not logging in both file and console

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I set Winston log level to ***debug*** in both file and console transports. ***verbose*** logger is not getting logged. Below is the winston code:

```
    var loglevel = 'debug'

    var options = {
file: {
    level: loglevel,
    filename: logfileName
    , handleExceptions: true
    , json: true
    , maxsize: 5242880
    , maxFiles: 5 // 5MB
    , colorize: true,
},

console: {
    level: loglevel
    , handleExceptions: true
    , json: true
    , colorize: true
    , "outputCapture": "std"
}
```

};

```
    var logger = new winston.Logger({
transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
],
exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
```

});

When I import winston logger in other .js file and use it, then it's not logging verbose log level. logger code is as below:

```
    logger.verbose("req payload verbose :: "+JSON.stringify(request.payload));
```

Comment: Make sure the log path exists

Comment: I can't replicate this: https://repl.it/@mihaifm/winstonLogLevel

Comment: All higher log levels are getting logged(info, error, warn). But verbose and debug are not logging